# Can you use "certificate" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I have consulted dictionaries and Google, but I'm still not sure whether "certificate" is the correct word for signed transcripts of registration details, course credits and the like that students can get from the department office at uni. If "certificate" is indeed the correct word, can I talk about a "registration certificate" when I intend a signed transcript of details about what courses a certain student is enrolled in? I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out here :)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what the official term is but _certificate_ would be understood and may even be the best option.

Comment: In the U.S., that would be called a “transcript” or an”official transcript.” It might also be called a “certified transcript.” I do not think “certificate” would be understood as a transcript because the word certificate has a much broader meaning than just a school transcript.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks! I see that you and Jeff give the opposite answers, so I'm curious whether you're a speaker of BrE rather than AmE?

Comment: @JeffMorrow Thanks! "Official transcript" sounds good :) So, would that be "Official registration transcript" then?

Comment: As I mentioned I was not sure what the official term was since we do not have such things as far as I am aware. The document you get with a record of what school leaving exams you passed with their grades we know as a certificate. If you need to be understood in the US then @JeffMorrow answer is correct.

Comment: OK: Do you mean this: **An official record of all the courses you took and marks (grades) you received**? Please be aware that non-native speakers often confuse registration and record. However, this transcript (AmE) does not show course enrollment per se. Only completed courses or ones you dropped. Also, here, certificate is completely wrong.

Comment: Universities (colleges) do not issue certificates. But they might certify some document.

Comment: @Lambie, pretty good, but I think you are leaving out graduation certificates!

Comment: @CorvusB No, no and no. Graduation diploma or degree.

Comment: Uhh, @Lambie, *di·plo·ma  /dəˈplōmə/
noun
a certificate awarded by an educational establishment to show that someone has successfully completed a course of study.  *
    I would agree that diploma and degree are more common, but they are all certificates.

Comment: @CorvusB Most people would not call a degree or diploma a certificate. There actually are some courses at unis where they do give you a certificate for a non-degree course. I know because I have one from Georgetown in translation. I also have the BS.

Comment: @Lambie I totally agree about how most people would use the words! And that certificate, in the US, is more commonly applied to a single course of study, usually outside the scope of university degree studies. But certificate would still be understood when used in this manner (as synonymous).

Comment: @Lambie *Thank you*! Yes, that's exactly what I mean, although including transcripts that you can get at any point during your studies, showing what you've done so far (that is, including courses that you've only just started). As for registration and record I *think* I know the difference – it's correct to say that a student is *registered* on a course, right? What you say about the difference between issuing certificates and certifying documents, finally, makes so much sense! I think this was exactly why "certificate" didn't sit right with me :)

Comment: @CorvusB What you're saying is that "certificate" is a hypernym of diploma?

Comment: No, Helen. A student **is enrolled or signed up for a course**. :)  And registered at a university or college to attend courses, an administrative term. Re certifying in English: Anyone can certify a written document by writing: I hereby certify blah blah blah. Certified by some institution. However, that certified document is just that. And is not necessarily a certificate.

Comment: @Lambie Right, yes - that's what I meant; it was the administrative term I was after when I talked about being registered :) Thanks for the clarification though. And yes, exactly - makes perfect sense what you're saying about certifying and certificate :)

Comment: You know I have translated this college stuff for years and years which is really why I know about it. A normal person wouldn't unless they worked in this area. :)

Comment: @Lambie :) Well – lucky for me! :)

Comment: @Helen I hadn't thought of certificate as a hypernym of diploma, although it might technically be so (dictionary definition). I would think it a synonym, with overlapping areas of meaning or usage with diploma. That might be a good topic for a question or for discussion! I do see, though, from my previous comments, why you are thinking of "hypernym" in this case!

Comment: @Helen for a more nuanced guide to common usage difference between certificate, diploma, and degree see https://potomac.edu/certificate-vs-diploma-vs-degree/. To see "certificate" used as a hypernym of diploma, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma.

Comment: @CorvusB Thanks for your clarification and links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S. certificate would not be understood when requesting a student's records. To get a record of courses taken and/or scholastic awards achieved one would be requesting a transcript, or one would simply request the student's records. A certificate would be the document one receives at graduation, attesting that the student did indeed graduate. Transcripts, to my knowledge, are not certified either, although you would get official transcripts, meaning there is some level of attested accuracy. Graduation certificates (diplomas) would be signed by the appropriate authorities.

As for the use of registration, in the US that is simply the act of signing up for the school or for classes. It would never refer to scholastic or academic records. If one wanted the current course schedule, then one could request a list of courses the student is registered* in. Once the courses have been completed, and exams taken, then the student will no longer be registered in those courses, and the courses will become part of the student's academic records. In the US, *register* as a list (noun) would not be used for academic records.**

Lastly, this is all hypothetical. I am reasonably certain that, if a 3rd party did request a student's records in the US, in any sense discussed here, they would be turned down flat, as it would be an invasion of privacy. They could find out if the student graduated, and what their major area of study was, but I think that would be about it. Of course, a student may request their own records.

*A comment has been made that the use of registration here is incorrect, and enroll would be preferred. In my experience this is not a distinction that is commonly made. This distinction may or may not be correct, I could not say. However, in my experience the two are nearly interchangeable, and this answer is regarding the usage of register/registration specifically.

**As a side-note for possible discussion, notice the differences in definition of *register* [provided by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=register) (from Oxford Dictionaries) and that provided by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/register). The definition provided by the Oxford Dictionaries might be broadly taken to be usable for student records, whereas that provided by the Cambridge Dictionary does not seem to extend that broadly.

Comment: Thanks! Ah, yes - I didn't mean someone else could request any transcripts; I meant that any one student can request a transcript of their *own* achievements etc :)

Comment: LOL! In which case, I might have to modify my answer to include that possibility! I don't know why I thought you were asking as though a 3rd party was making the request!

Comment: @Helen Also, although perhaps a bit nitpickey, while Lambie is correct about the correct usage of "registered in" vs "enrolled in" when speaking of classes, I don't recall students making such fine distinctions. A university staffer might make that distinction, though. Regardless, I may modify my answer to use "enrolled" rather than "registered", since these answers shouldn't lead readers to questionable usage.

Comment: @Helen You might also find some interesting trivia about the varying usage of diploma and certificate around the world in Wikipedia's page for "diploma". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., "official transcript" or "certified transcript" from X would be understood and would sound idiomatic. "Official registration transcript" sounds excessive.

I'd listen to @mdewey for British English.